# Activate fluid app pinned to status from Quicksilver

Tags: quicksilver, ios, fluid.app

I use [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com) apps that are pinned to my status bar. If I click on the icon in the status bar, the Fluid app will get focus. I'd like to be able to give an app focus from [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com) instead of having to click on the status bar icon. Is there any way to do that? Executing the corresponding app in /Applications doesn't have the desired effect.